# Pythagorean trinomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was messing around and discovered this neat little lemma.

Your task is to prove it.

**Lemma.** Let $(a,b,c)$ be a Pythagorean Triple ($a^2+b^2=c^2$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$). Then all four of the  quadratic trinomials

$$x^2 \pm cx \pm \frac 12ab$$

factor over the set of integers.

I've posted  my proof as an answer.

Comment: What is your question--find a proof of the lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $(a,b,c)$ be a Pythagorean Triple.

Taking that to mean that $c^2=a^2+b^2\,$.

> Then all four of the  quadratic trinomials $x^2 \color{red}{\pm} cx \color{blue}{\pm} \frac 12ab$ factor over the set of integers.

The discriminant of the quadratic is $\,c^2 \color{blue}{\mp} 2ab = a^2+b^2 \color{blue}{\mp} 2ab = (a \color{blue}{\mp} b)^2\,$, so its roots are $\,\displaystyle x_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}\big(\color{red}{\mp} c \pm (a \color{blue}{\mp} b)\big)$, and the polynomial factors as $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$. All that's left to note is that $x_{1,2}$ are integers, because the perimeter of a pythagorean triangle is always even.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   \left(x + \frac 12(c+a+b)\right)\left(x + \frac 12(c-a-b)\right)
   &= x^2 + cx + \frac 14(c^2-(a+b)^2) \\
   &= x^2 + cx + \frac 14(a^2+b^2 - a^2 - 2ab - b^2) \\
   &= x^2+cx - \frac 12ab
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   \left(x - \frac 12(c+a+b)\right)\left(x - \frac 12(c-a-b)\right)
   &= x^2 - cx + \frac 14(c^2-(a+b)^2) \\
   &= x^2 - cx + \frac 14(a^2+b^2 - a^2 - 2ab - b^2) \\
   &= x^2 - cx - \frac 12ab
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   \left(x + \frac 12(c-a+b)\right)\left(x + \frac 12(c+a-b)\right)
   &= x^2 + cx + \frac 14(c^2-(a-b)^2) \\
   &= x^2 + cx + \frac 14(a^2+b^2 - a^2 + 2ab - b^2) \\
   &= x^2+cx + \frac 12ab
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   \left(x - \frac 12(c-a+b)\right)\left(x - \frac 12(c+a-b)\right)
   &= x^2 - cx + \frac 14(c^2-(a-b)^2) \\
   &= x^2 - cx + \frac 14(a^2+b^2 - a^2 + 2ab - b^2) \\
   &= x^2 - cx + \frac 12ab
\end{align}

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your algebra.  Please check.  Even when providing a "self-answer" the site's standards for writing good Answers apply.  You might have included this (in hidden text, if you insist) in the body of the Question.  That is, by the way, not very clear as to what you are asking, so many Readers may wonder what responses you really want.

Comment: @hardmath - sorry I fixed it